# changing id to populate html table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to populate 10 frames from Html table with 2 values that come from two randomly generated numbers, play1 and play2, I can populate the first two spots but afterwords I cannot populate the rest as I'm failing to change the variables newId1 and newId2.

```js
var controlVariable = 1;

function r(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min;
}

var min = 0;
var max = 10;
var play1;
var play2;
var frame = 1; 
var newId1 = "s1f1";
var newId2 = "s2f1";

function myFunction() {
  if (controlVariable == 1) {
    play1 = r(min, max);
    if(play1 === 10) {
      // add value to first spot 
      newId1 = "s1f" + frame;
      document.getElementById(newId1).innerHTML = play1;
      frame++; 
    } else {
      //add value to first spot
      document.getElementById(newId1).innerHTML = play1;
      controlVariable++; 
    }
     
  }
  else if (controlVariable == 2) { 
    play2 = r(min, max - (play1-min));
    controlVariable = 1;
    // add value to second spot
    newId2 = "s2f"+frame; 
    document.getElementById(newId2).innerHTML = play2;
    frame++;
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = [play1, play2];
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
 

<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 1</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 2</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 3</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 4</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 5</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 6</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 7</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 8</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 9</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f1"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f1"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f2"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f2"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f3"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f3"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f4"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f4"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f5"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f5"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f6"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f6"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f7"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f7"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f8"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f8"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f9"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f9"></td>
    <td colspan="2" id="s1f10"></td>
    <td colspan="2" id="s2f10"></td>
    <td colspan="2" id="s3f10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

How can I do this? I'm starting to think i'm overcomplicating this.

Comment: var newId1 = "s1f1";
     var newId2 = "s2f1"; you putting a static id's

Comment: changed it now, and still it just adds values to the second spots of each frame

Comment: Everything will be easier if you treat your td elements as an array rather than trying to manage id names as numbers. Give the td elements a class, then use `var frames = document.querySelectorAll(".classname")` to get them. It will be much easier to then just use `frame[n]` to get a particular frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are changing `newId` (in `newId = "s1f"+frame;`) but you never use it. You only use newId1 and newId2.

Comment: changed it now, and still it just adds values to the second spots of each frame, i'll be editing the request shortly so you can see what is happening

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the line `newId = "s1f"+frame;`.

The variable `newId` has not been defined, and it's not referenced anywhere in the code except where you set it. Because of this, your code will only set the value for the default box (which you've designated as `s1f1`)

Change `newId` to `newId1` and you should be good to go!

Comment: changed it now, and still it just adds values to the second spots of each frame, i'll be editing the request shortly so you can see what is happening

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't really what you asked, but I'm posting anyway at the risk of getting downvoted. Any time you find yourself managing id names by concatenating a counter you need to ask yourself if you should be using an array. I think you absolutely should in this case because it will be much easier to manage your logic. I'm not 100% what the game is supposed to do, but it looks like you are keeping track of bowling scores. Consider something like this instead:

Fist, make your html look like this:

```
<td class="dd" colspan="3"></td>
<td class="dd" colspan="3"></td>
```

Now you can grab all of the `<td>` elements with `document.querySelectorAll()` and have them as an array.

```
function r(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min;
}
var min = 0;
var max = 10;
var roll = 0;
var frame = 0

var play;

var tds = document.querySelectorAll('.dd')

function myFunction() {
  var play = r(min, max);

  //figure out which element you should be writing to based on frame and roll number
  tds[frame * 2 + roll].innerHTML = play

// now the logic of the game is easy to understand

// if you roll a strike, go to the next frame:
  if (play === 10) {
    frame ++;
    roll = 0
    return
  }

  // first roll? stay in the same frame, go to roll two
  if (roll == 0) {
    //you can't roll more than the number of pins
    max = max - play
    roll ++
    return 
  }

  // otherwise reset and go to the next frame
  max = 10
  roll = 0
  frame++
}
```

So now the logic actually follows the logic of the game a little. The last frame, of course will require a little work, but if should be easier.There are probably even better variations, but the basic idea is to work with a list rather than manage string id names.

Comment: I see what you did there, I'll be sure to give it a try, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
  var controlVariable = 1;

  function r(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min;
  }

  var min = 0;
  var max = 10;
  var play1;
  var play2;
  var frame = 1; 
  var newId1 = "s1f";
  var newId2 = "s2f";

  function myFunction() {
    if (controlVariable == 1) {
      play1 = r(min, max);
      if(play1 === 10) {
        // add value to first spot 
        newId = "s1f"+frame;
        document.getElementById(newId).innerHTML = play1;
        frame++; 
      } else {
        //add value to first spot
        newId = "s1f"+frame;
        document.getElementById(newId).innerHTML = play1;
        controlVariable++; 
      }

    }
    else if (controlVariable == 2) {
      play2 = r(min, max - (play1-min));
      controlVariable = 1;
      // add value to second spot
      document.getElementById(newId2).innerHTML = play1;
      frame++;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = [play1, play2];
  }
  </script>
```